# Modify affine transformation matrix to match change in shape origin

Tags: matrices, geometry, affine-geometry

Given I have a 2D affine transform described by the matrix:

```
[ a  c  tx ]
[ b  d  ty ]
[ 0  0  1  ]
```

Such that:

```
[ x ]   [ a  c  tx ] [ x ]   [ a * x + c * y + tx ]
[ y ] = [ b  d  ty ] [ y ] = [ b * x + d * y + ty ]
[ 1 ]   [ 0  0  1  ] [ 1 ]   [         1          ]
```

I have a shape that starts at `[-(width/2), -(height/2)]` so that it is centred about `[0, 0]`.

I want to change the origin of the shape so that it starts at `[0,0]` but I want its transformed coordinates to be the same.

How do I update the matrix to map the objects new origin to the same end position?

I seem to be failing at the point where when `x` or `y` equals = 0 everything just cancels out and becomes:

```
[ tx ]
[ ty ]
[ 1  ]
```

Comment: The general form of an affin transformation is $y=Tx+b$, where $b$ is the translation vector. In your case $b$ depends on $x$, which is illegal.

Comment: @zoli I don't quite understand. This follows the formula given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations and the result is just a multiplication of the two matrices. `b` In my formula affects rotation and skew along the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

I realised the way to do this is to form a new matrix:

```
[ a  c  ox ]
[ b  d  oy ]
[ 0  0  1  ]
```

Where:

- `w = -(width / 2)`
- `h = -(height / 2)`
- `ox = tx + aw + ch`
- `oy = ty + bw + dh`